# How to find the start and end of a RxJS.ajax call?

Tags: ajax, angular, rxjs, reactive

I'm using [RxJS.ajax](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS-DOM/blob/master/doc/operators/ajax.md) call to check whether a product is available in the database. The call will take 2 to 4 seconds to come back. Within that time I want to display a message saying `searching for product`.

Are there any events triggered by **RxJS.ajax** to know the call has started and ended? Or are there other RxJS calls available to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1):

Use the progressObserver: 'An optional Observer which listen to XHR2 progress events or error timeout values.'